# How to implement a global setUp() for multiprocessing using nosetests

Tags: python, multiprocessing, nosetests

So far I've used nosetests with just one process and everything works fine.

To ensure my setUp is only executed once, I'm using a boolean var.

```
def setUp(self):
  if not self.setupOk:
    selTest.setupOk = True
    # start selenium
    # do other stuff which will be needed for all other tests to be able to run
```

Now I would like to run nosetests with the option --processes=5

How can I ensure that setUp(self) is only execued by one process (while the other processes are waiting).

I've tried to work with

```
def setUp(self):
  lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
  lock.acquire()
      if not self.setupOk:
        selTest.setupOk = True
        # start selenium
        # do other stuff which will be needed for all other tests to be able to run 
  lock.release()
```

but this doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

setUp will be called before every test is run.  If you want a method to execute just once, you can use setUpClass:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    print "do stuff which needs to be run once"
```